# Spring Beans not Initialized Completely

Tags: spring, thread-sleep

I am facing a strange problem with Spring, a bean is not initialized completely with injected dependency. It works fine if a thread sleep of minimal 5 seconds is introduced before accessing that bean.

This is not a case of notify/wait as this is in control of Spring.

Another  pointer is that the bean's methods are static and variable is also static.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Here's the code

```
    public final class UserPreferencesUtils {


        /** siamHandlerFacade variable. */
        private static SiamHandlerFacade siamHandlerFacade;

    =====
    public static String getSubscriberXXXX() {
    try {
                // Here the above is being used
                // This method is also static
                showSubscriberProfile = siamHandlerFacade
                        .retrieveSubscriberProfile(retrieveSubscriberProfile);
            } catch (WebServiceClientException ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
```

bean configuration

```
    <bean id="userPreferenceUtils" class="aero.sita.voyager.ias.client.commons.utils.UserPreferencesUtils">
     <property name="siamHandlerFacade" ref="siamServiceManagerRemoteService"></property>
     <property name="queryLMData" ref="queryLMData"></property>

     </bean>

    <bean id="siamServiceManagerRemoteService"
              class="aero.sita.voyager.ias.client.commons.webserviceproxy.SiamHandlerFacadeImpl">
              <property name="siamWebServiceCallProxy" ref="siamWebServiceCallProxy"/>
               <property name="officeWebServiceCallProxy" ref="officeWebServiceCallProxy"/>
              <property name="subscriberWebServiceCallProxy" ref="subscriberWebServiceCallProxy"/>
              <property name="masterAgreementWebServiceCallProxy" ref="masterAgreementWebServiceCallProxy"/>
              <property name="agreementWebServiceCallProxy" ref="agreementWebServiceCallProxy"/>
              <property name="userProfileWebServiceCallProxy" ref="userProfileWebServiceCallProxy"/>
      </bean>
```

Comment: Please share your code. Spring configuration and beans.

Comment: Please share a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for us to help. The information provided is insufficient and its likely that question may be flagged for closure.

Comment: Thanks I have added code snapshot and bean configuration

Comment: The short answer don't use static methods for this, as you don't have any garantue in which order beans are initialized especially you start using static method references. You should be injecting the dependencies rather than use that ugly singleton with static methods.